# Java Enum toString() method

Tags: java, enums

I have several Java enums using underscores to separate words.  In each of my enums I have a toString method which is implemented as super.toString().replace("_", " ") so that I can display the String values on a GUI without the underscores.  Is there some way I can have all my enums use this toString method without duplicating it across all of them?  If this were a regular class the answer is simple, implement toString() then have all my classes that need that implementation extend that class, but enums can't extend anything, not even another enum.

```
public enum Example1 {
    HELLO_WORLD, HELLO_EARTH, HELLO_GLOBE
    @Override public String toString() {
        return super.toString().replace("_", " ");
    }
}
public enum Example2 {
    ANSWER_1, ANSWER_2, ANSWER_3
    @Override public String toString() {
        return super.toString().replace("_", " ");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution that doesn't duplicate this toString() method across all enums?

Comment: Use a helper method when printing your enums.

Comment: Is it necessary to use "enum"? Or can you change your implementation to type safe enums so you can do some inheritance?

Comment: @Neel I see your point, forgetting the Java enum and use the method from before Java actually recognized enums.  That's a good idea.

Comment: updated with typesafe enum guideline... you might need to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String toString(Enum<?> enumVal) {
    return String.valueOf(enumVal).replace("_", " ");
}
```

Usage:

```
String asString = toString(HELLO_WORLD);
```

or,

```
String asString = toString(ANSWER_1);
```

Typesafe approach:

```
public abstract class MyEnum<E extends MyEnum<E>> {

    protected MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    protected String name() {
        return name;
    };

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return name().replace("_", " ");
    }
}

public final static class Example1 extends MyEnum<Example1> {
    public static final Example1 HELLO_WORLD = new Example1("HELLO_WORLD");

    protected Example1(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(Example1.HELLO_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8 we can pull in methods using interfaces so you can now actually add functionality to enums through a form of inheritance.

```
public interface HasName {
    public String name();
}

public interface PoliteEnum extends HasName {
    default String politeName() {
        return name().replace("_", " ");
    }
}

public enum X implements PoliteEnum {
    A_For_Ism, B_For_Mutton, C_Forth_Highlanders;
}

public void test() {
    for (X x : X.values()) {
        System.out.println(x.politeName());
    }
}
```

prints

```
A For Ism
B For Mutton
C Forth Highlanders
```

I accept that it is not as neat as overriding `toString` because you cannot override an `Object` method in the `default` but it certainly leaves your `enum` tidy.

Answer (score 1):

Declare some helper method like

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> String toString(Enum<E> value) {
    return value.name().replace("_", ""); // use name() as suggested in comments
}
```

Whenever you want to print an `enum`, use it

```
String valueToPrint = YourHelperClass.toString(Example2.ANSWER_1);
```

In Java 8, you could use an interface with a default implementation which all your enums implement (but don't override).

Comment: Why would I need E? This helper method should work for any Enum, no?

Comment: @Sotirios I though of this too, but in that case my team and I would have to remember to use the helper class (I know, I know).  The simplicity of "The answer is: " + enumInstance; automatically calls toString() for me and is already scattered throughout my code.

Comment: You can replace `.toString()` with `.name()` in this example since by default, this is what an `Enum` does

Comment: @Flappjakk You don't need `E`, you can use a wildcard (I just try to avoid them). Java 8 will be here soon for the best solution.