# Java enum autogenerate getInstance method?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, auto-generate

Lets say I have the following java enum

```
public enum Color {
  RED(10),
  GREEN(22),
  BLUE(33);

  private int value;

  Color(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int intValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

In order to be able to obtain a color instance by a given integer value I need to add method like this:

```
public static Color getInstance(int value) {
  switch (value) {
    case 10: return RED;
    case 22: return GREEN;
    case 33: return BLUE;
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid color value");
  }
}
```

Is it possible this method to be autogenerated from the IDE? (Preferably IntelliJ)?

Comment: How many of such `enum`s do you expect to write in your lifetime?

Comment: I work on a project where many enums are to be introduced with much more than three values inside. Its a real time waste to code all this stuff by hand.

Comment: For the love of god, use universal color codes. It will make your life as well as the developer/s, who will come after you, a bit easier. this way, you don't deal with this enum thing.

Comment: @WeareBorg Totally agreed :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of repeating the code in every `enum`, you may implement a central utility method for all kinds of enums with an `int` value. This is possible since `enum`s can implement interfaces, hence you can define a uniform way of accessing the `int` value:

```
public interface IntValued {
    int intValue();
}
/** get the particular {@link IntValued} {@code enum} constant. */
public static <T extends Enum<T>&IntValued> T get(Class<T> type, int value) {
    return type.cast(GET.get(type).apply(value));
}
private static ClassValue<IntFunction<Enum>> GET = new ClassValue<IntFunction<Enum>>() {
    protected IntFunction<Enum> computeValue(Class<?> type) {
        return prepare(type);
    }
};
// invoked only once per enum type
static IntFunction<Enum> prepare(Class<?> type) {
    Enum[] values=type.asSubclass(Enum.class).getEnumConstants();
    if(values.length==0) return i -> null;
    IntSummaryStatistics s=Arrays.stream(values)
        .mapToInt(o -> ((IntValued)o).intValue())
        .summaryStatistics();
    int min=s.getMin(), max=s.getMax();
    if((max-min+1)<s.getCount()*2) {
        Enum[] linear=new Enum[max-min+1];
        for(Enum e: values) linear[((IntValued)e).intValue()-min]=e;
        return i -> i<min||i>max? null: linear[i-min];
    }
    Map<Integer, Enum> map = Arrays.stream(values).collect(
        Collectors.toMap(o -> ((IntValued)o).intValue(), Function.identity()));
    return map::get;
}
```

This uses `ClassValue`, a JRE provided way of associating custom meta data to a class. `ClassValue` takes care of invoking the initialization code only once and still allows garbage collection/ class unloading. The code above dynamically determines which lookup structure to use. If the `int` values of a particular `enum` type are dense, it uses an array, otherwise it resorts to a `Map`.

You can use it as follows:

```
public enum Color implements IntValued {
    RED(10),
    GREEN(22),
    BLUE(33);

    private int value;

    Color(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public int intValue() {
      return value;
    }
}
```

```
Color color=get(Color.class, 22);
System.out.println(color);
```

Note that this solution, unlike generated `switch` statements, does not break if these int values are changed.

Comment: Nice! I believe it was you that pointed out to me some time ago that `Class<T>` has a `cast` method. `return type.cast(GET.get(type).apply(value));` would avoid an *evil* cast.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: you are right; here it backfires that Netbeans does not generate all kinds of unchecked warnings in its default configuration.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex.  Why not just a static method with a signature like `public static <T extends IntValued> Map<Integer, T> mapByValue(Collection<T> values)`, whose body is your second-to-last statement?  It doesn't even need to be specific to enum types.

Comment: @VGR: The whole point is that this code does *not* populate a map each time you call the `get` method. It does so at most one time for a concrete `enum`, but, as already explained, may even use a faster array-based accessor, if the `int` values are dense. Each subsequent invocation will reuse that accessor function created on the first call. The goal was to be as fast as the `switch` statement of the question.

Comment: Couldn't the Map be a lazily populated, unmodifiable singleton?

Comment: @VGR: it seems you still don’t understand that this method does *not* use a map in all cases. There are three different result functions and, since you can’t implement a map via lambda expression, enforcing it to return a `Map` would require to create additional classes for that. Besides that, you still need a map instance per `enum` and thus have implement a way to cache these results and that’s what this solution is about. Except that it uses an `IntFunction` instead of a `Map` but replacing `IntFunction` with `Map` would not make anything simpler…

Comment: I got that, I just don't understand the need for so much optimization.  What's wrong with a Map for every class?  How many enum types could there possibly be?  Even a thousand small Maps doesn't seem like a penalty to me.

Comment: @VGR: that’s the premise of the question. If you look at the comments there, I already asked, how much of these `enum` types are expected. This solution is for the OP’s assumption that the number is so large that auto-generated code per `enum` would be reasonable. Thus, I provided a solution which removes the need to add code to each `enum` type but is on par with the original `switch` solution’s performance (`tableswitch` for dense numbers and `lookupswitch` for the others). There wouldn’t be much problems with a map per type, but this solution is also to avoid a map *per invocation*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can make use of `default` methods in `interface` to add functionality to any class - even `enum`s.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084348/823393) where I add a reverse-lookup to an `enum` just by making it `implement ReverseLookup`.