# Multiple Java 8 Enums with same methods

Tags: java, enums, java-8

I have a series of enums which look like this except that the name and values are different:

```
/* Bone Diagnosis. Value is internal code stored in database. */
public enum BoneDiagnosis {
    NORMAL(121),
    ELEVATED(207),
    OSTEOPENIA(314),
    OSTEOPOROSIS(315);

    private int value;
    BoneDiagnosis(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /** Get localized text for the enumeration. */
    public String getText() {
        return MainProgram.localize(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase() + ".VALUE." + this.name());
    }

    /** Convert enumeration to predetermined database value. */
    public int toDB() {
        return value;
    }

    /** Convert a value read from the database back into an enumeration. */
    public static BoneDiagnosis fromDB(final Integer v) {
        if (v != null) {
            for (final BoneDiagnosis pc : values()) {
                if (v == pc.toDB()) {
                    return pc;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know I cannot extend enums, but is there some way to abstract this design to remove all the duplicate code in toDB(), fromDB(), and getText() that each class has? I looked at other questions like [Is it possible to extend enum in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22083689/1663987) which had an example using an interface, but I could not figure out how to handle the constructor and the static method. I also cannot figure out how to remove the explicit reference to type BoneDiagnosis in the fromDB() method.

My dream would be to have each class merely be defined something like what follows, with all the other support wrapped up in whatever BoneDiagnosisComplexTypeDefinition is. Is this possible?

```
public enum BoneDiagnosisComplexTypeDefinition {
    NORMAL(121),
    ELEVATED(207);
    OSTEOPENIA(314),
    OSTEOPOROSIS(315)
}
```

Comment: "_Prefer composition over inheritance_". Create an `EnumIndexTransformer` class that you can compose into your `enum` then delegate to that. Your `Enum` can also `implements` an `interface` - have an `Indexable<I>` that exposes those methods.

Comment: Your code will not compile.  the ; must be after OSTEOPOROSIS not after ELEVATED

Comment: @DwB sorry, I introduced a typo while munging the code to protect the innocent and client

Comment: I would suggest that if you have an extensive hierarchy of enums, a better pattern might be to create a hierarchy of entities with whatever hierarchical behavior you need, and to store the values in a persistent store.

Answer (score 6):

You can minimize the per-`enum` code and the per-operation overhead using

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD) @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DbId {
    int value();
}
final class Helper extends ClassValue<Map<Object,Object>> {
    static final Helper INSTANCE = new Helper();

    @Override protected Map<Object, Object> computeValue(Class<?> type) {
        Map<Object,Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        for(Field f: type.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(f.isEnumConstant()) try {
                Object constant = f.get(null);
                Integer id = f.getAnnotation(DbId.class).value();
                m.put(id, constant);
                m.put(constant, id);
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
    }
}
public interface Common {
    String name();
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> getDeclaringClass(); 
    default int toDB() {
        return (Integer)Helper.INSTANCE.get(getDeclaringClass()).get(this);
    }
    default String getText() {
        return MainProgram.localize(
            getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase() + ".VALUE." + name());
    }
    static <T extends Enum<T>&Common> T fromDB(Class<T> type, int id) {
        return type.cast(Helper.INSTANCE.get(type).get(id));
    }
}
```

```
public enum BoneDiagnosis implements Common {
    @DbId(121) NORMAL,
    @DbId(207) ELEVATED,
    @DbId(314) OSTEOPENIA,
    @DbId(315) OSTEOPOROSIS;
}
```

Test example

```
int id = BoneDiagnosis.OSTEOPENIA.toDB();
System.out.println("id = " + id);
BoneDiagnosis d = Common.fromDB(BoneDiagnosis.class, id);
System.out.println("text = " + d.getText());
```

Note that the reflective operations are only performed once per class using `ClassValue` which is especially designed for caching per-class meta data efficiently, thread safe and without preventing class unloading in environments where it matters. The actual `toDB` and `fromDB` are reduced to a hash lookups.

By the way, it’s important that this code uses `getDeclaringClass()` rather than `getClass()` as enums may have specializations like in `enum Foo { BAR { … } … }` where `getClass()` returns the specialization class rather than the `enum` type.

Comment: That `ClassValue` thing is fancy. I still find it fascinating that even after years of Java, there are new things.

Answer (score 3):

The interface approach is the only way to go. Here is another way to leverage interfaces to minimize code duplication in your enums.

**Update:**

Some have complained about reflection and casting. Here are two options without need for casting and one that does not require reflection.

**Option1 (clean no reflection but requires extra method in enums):**

```
 public static interface BoneDiagnosisType{

    public String name();

    public int getValue();

    default int toDB() {
        return getValue();
    }

    default String getText(){
        return MainProgram.localize( this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase() + ".VALUE." + name() );            
    }


    public static < E extends Enum<E> & BoneDiagnosisType > E fromDB(Class<E> eClass, Integer v) {
        if (v != null) {
            for ( final E pc : eClass.getEnumConstants() ) {
                if ( v == pc.toDB() ) {
                    return pc;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    } 
}

public static enum BoneDiagnosis1 implements BoneDiagnosisType{
    NORMAL(121),
    ELEVATED(207),
    OSTEOPENIA(314),
    OSTEOPOROSIS(315);

    int value;

    BoneDiagnosis1(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}

public static enum BoneDiagnosis2 implements BoneDiagnosisType{
    NORMAL(1121),
    ELEVATED(1207),
    OSTEOPENIA(1314),
    OSTEOPOROSIS(1315);

    int value;

    BoneDiagnosis2(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Option2 (requires reflection keeps enums as simple as possible):**

```
public static interface BoneDiagnosisType{

        public String name();

        default int toDB() {
            try{
                Class<?> clazz = getClass();            
                Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("value");
                return field.getInt(this);
            }catch(RuntimeException e){
                throw e;
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        default String getText(){
            return MainProgram.localize( this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase() + ".VALUE." + name() );            
        }


        public static < E extends Enum<E> & BoneDiagnosisType > E fromDB(Class<E> eClass, Integer v) {
            if (v != null) {
                for ( final E pc : eClass.getEnumConstants() ) {
                    if ( v == pc.toDB() ) {
                        return pc;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }  
    }


    public static enum BoneDiagnosis1 implements BoneDiagnosisType{
        NORMAL(121),
        ELEVATED(207),
        OSTEOPENIA(314),
        OSTEOPOROSIS(315);

        int value;

        BoneDiagnosis1(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static enum BoneDiagnosis2 implements BoneDiagnosisType{
        NORMAL(1121),
        ELEVATED(1207),
        OSTEOPENIA(1314),
        OSTEOPOROSIS(1315);

        int value;

        BoneDiagnosis2(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

And the sample printout:

```
System.out.println( BoneDiagnosis1.NORMAL.toDB() + " : " + BoneDiagnosis1.NORMAL.getText() + " : " + 
BoneDiagnosisType.fromDB( BoneDiagnosis1.class, 121 ) );

System.out.println( BoneDiagnosis1.ELEVATED.toDB() + " : " + BoneDiagnosis1.ELEVATED.getText() + " : " + 
BoneDiagnosisType.fromDB( BoneDiagnosis1.class, 207 ) );

System.out.println( BoneDiagnosis2.NORMAL.toDB() + " : " + BoneDiagnosis2.NORMAL.getText() + " : " + 
BoneDiagnosisType.fromDB( BoneDiagnosis2.class, 1121 ) );

System.out.println( BoneDiagnosis2.ELEVATED.toDB() + " : " + BoneDiagnosis2.ELEVATED.getText() + " : " + 
BoneDiagnosisType.fromDB( BoneDiagnosis2.class, 1207 ) );
```

will give:

121 : BONEDIAGNOSIS1.VALUE.NORMAL : NORMAL

207 : BONEDIAGNOSIS1.VALUE.ELEVATED : ELEVATED

1121 : BONEDIAGNOSIS2.VALUE.NORMAL : NORMAL

1207: BONEDIAGNOSIS2.VALUE.ELEVATED : ELEVATED

Comment: this is neat. at a high level, why is eClass needed as a parameter to fromDB()? how is it different from <E> ? is something like BoneDiagnosis2.fromDB(intval) not possible? And can you explain needing "< E extends Enum<E> & BoneDiagnosisType<E> >"? BoneDiagnosisType already extends type 'E extends Enum<E>', so why are both bounds needed?

Comment: The reason we need eClass is that the method is static and there is no way for us to know which enum `values` method to call. By using the class we can do the what `values` does using `class.getEnumConstants`.

The reason we need both types in generic is that because we are working with `BoneDiagnosisType` interface which is not enum (we cant extend enum). Using both will make sure that `class.getEnumConstants` will give us BoneDiagnosisType without the need for casting.

Comment: I see now; at first glance and because it was an interface, I got confused and thought fromDB() was a static instance in the type BONEDIAGNOSIS2 as well as another in BONEDIAGNOSIS1, but it's only a static part of BoneDiagnosisType. Thanks!

Comment: This is rife with bad programming practices:  The use of `setAccessible`;  the use of reflection, unseen by writers of enum classes;  the use of ‘catch (Exception e)’ instead of `catch (ReflectiveOperationException e)`;  the use of `(E) this` instead of just `+ this` (and the resulting need for a @SuppressWarnings).  This may be functionally correct, but it’s a poor solution.

Comment: @simpleuser. I did update my answer with 2 options that dont require casting and one that is also does not require reflection and is preferred approach.

Comment: @tsolakp thank you very much, for both example. there is a lot of good knowledge in your response, and I appreciate the time you took to answer and then improve it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could go about it using what some call the "virtual field pattern." It reduces the amount of repeated code per enum to one getter and one field. It also avoids reflection.

First create an interface for all the methods your enums have in common. In this example we'll call it `Common`.

```
public interface Common {

    int getId();

    String getName();
}
```

Create another interface that extends `Common`. This will have only one abstract method, which just returns an instance of `Common`. Give the other methods a default implementation that delegates to the `Common` instance.

```
public interface VirtualCommon extends Common {

    Common getCommon();

    @Override
    default int getId() {
        return getCommon().getId();
    }

    @Override
    default String getName() {
        return getCommon().getName();
    }
}
```

Now create a concrete implementation of `Common`.

```
public class CommonImpl implements Common {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public CommonImpl(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to save a few lines of code, instead of `CommonImpl` you can put a static method on `Common` that returns an anonymous class.

```
static Common of(final int id, final String name) {
    return new Common() {
        @Override
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    };
}
```

Now you can create each of your enums and they'll only need one field and one getter. Any class or enum that implements `VirtualCommon` will **be** a `Common` because it **has** a `Common`.

```
public enum EnumImpl implements VirtualCommon {

    ALPHA(1, "Alpha"),
    BETA(2, "Beta"),
    DELTA(3, "Delta"),
    GAMMA(4, "Gamma");

    private final Common common;

    EnumImpl(int id, String name) {
        this.common = new CommonImpl(id, name);
    }

    @Override
    public Common getCommon() {
        return this.common;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution still has some boilerplate bridging code.

Use an `Interface` to define the calling interface and implement the common code in some class.
Here is a simple example:

File: BoneDiagnosis.java

```
public enum BoneDiagnosis
implements
    CommonStuffs
{
  NORMAL(121),
  ELEVATED(207),
  OSTEOPENIA(314),
  OSTEOPOROSIS(315);

  private CommonStuffsImpl commonStuffsImpl;
  private int value;

  BoneDiagnosis(final int theValue)
  {
      value = theValue;

      commonStuffsImpl = new CommonStuffsImpl();
  }

  @Override
    public int toDB()
  {
    return commonStuffsImpl.toDBImplementation(value);
  }
}
```

File: CommonStuffs.java

```
public interface CommonStuffs
{
    int toDB();
}
```

File: CommonStuffsImpl.java

```
public class CommonStuffsImpl
{
    public int toDBImplementation(
        final int value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```